# Using regex for multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

What is the best way of extracting expressions for the following lines using regex:

```
Sigma 0.10 index = $5.00
beta .05=$25.00
.35 index (or $12.5)
Gamma 0.07
```

In any of the case, I want to extract the numeric values from each line (for example "0.10" from line 1) and (if available) the dollar amount or "$5.00" for line 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
s="""Sigma 0.10 index = $5.00
beta .05=$25.00
.35 index (or $12.5)
Gamma 0.07"""
print re.findall(r'[0-9$.]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['0.10', '$5.00', '.05', '$25.00', '.35', '$12.5', '0.07']
```

More strict regex:

```
print re.findall(r'[$]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
```

Output:

```
['0.10', '$5.00', '$25.00', '$12.5', '0.07']
```

If you want to match `.05` also:

```
print re.findall(r'[$]?(?:\d*\.\d+)|\d+', s)
```

Output:

```
['0.10', '$5.00', '.05', '$25.00', '.35', '$12.5', '0.07']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the base regex would be: `\$?\d+(\.\d+)?`, which will get you the numbers. Unfortunately, I know regex in JavaScript/C# so not sure about how to do multiple lines in python. Should be a really simple flag though.

Comment: Can you explain why I need the `?` at the end.

Comment: `?` means maybe it's there, maybe it isn't. So for example `spams?` will match 'spam' or 'spams' because the `?` comes just after the 's'. However, if we use it with a group (something encased in `( )`) then it applies to the entire group. so `(\.\d+)?` means match if there is a decimal followed by some numbers... or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.MULTILINE` flag and `\n` to denote line breaks.

```
source = '''Sigma 0.10 index = $5.00
beta .05=$25.00
.35 index (or $12.5)
Gamma 0.07'''
import re

# only handles two top lines; extend to taste
rx = re.compile(
  'Sigma (\d*\.\d+) index = (\$\d*\.\d+)\nbeta (\d*\.\d+).*', 
   re.MULTILINE
)

print rx.search(source).groups()
# prints ('0.10', '$5.00', '.05')
```

Consider also `.split('\n')` on your line and the use of several simpler regexps, one per resulting line.

Comment: Splitting the input before parsing seems like a bad idea for both correctness and readability.

Comment: @siebz0r: splitting is parsing of newlines that are a part of source format. Seems legit to me.